# Can I change the view(pan/rotate) while performing an action?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, snapping

As an ex-C4D user I often need the function to zoom in and out, pan or rotate *during* or *while* I'm editing a vertex. When I use the vertex snap over an DWG drawing, I had to snap an intermediate point, pan my view to the point I want to snap to, because it's out of the display view, and then make a second final grab action to snap onto the point I wanted.

Is there any function *(with its respective shortcut)* to do this in Blender?

Comment: Not currently. Although it might be possible with a 3D Mouse build? I'm not quite sure. It also might be possible with python scripting but I'm not expert enough on that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't move the 3D view while editing something, even with a 3D mouse, at least in Blender 2.67b, from what I know.

For your "*snapping*" problem, I suggest you the use of the 3D cursor, by doing the following:

- place the 3D cursor at the exact point you want your vertex's final position (with *left click* in the view, or directly by entering the coordinates in the properties panel - *shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>* - or with the snap menu, see below)
- select your vertex
- hit <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to display the "snap" menu
- choose "*Selection to cursor*"

[image: Snap menu]

You'll notice that there is also "*Cursor to selected*" option available in this menu, allowing you to position the 3D cursor accurately at the selection's position.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Some model operations (like [knife](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide)) allow you to move the view while editing. Others like grab mode don't. There's no need to watch your transformation move along it's entire journey:

1. Select the vertex you wish to move.
2. Pan/zoom/rotate the view to the target snap point.
3. Then enter grab mode and snap way.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to rotate around a vertex or group of vertices you're editing, select it/them, and press the <kbd>.</kbd> key on the numpad

This will set your pivot point for the 3D view. Rotate the view by clicking your Middle Mouse Button, or click your mouse wheel (depends on your mouse).

To pan, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>MMB</kbd>. Do note that this will change the pivot point.

Comment: I think the OP meant "Can I move the view *while transforming the selection*?"